# how to return a value without exiting a function and storing it subsequently, in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, c++17, return-type

Here I'm trying to mimic data feed streaming from stock exchange using random number and subsequently store it in array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdlib.h>

long int prevcntr=0;

using namespace std;

std::pair<long int, double>feedgenerator(long int len)
{
    srand(time(0));
    for(long int itr=1;itr<=len;itr++)
    {
        return {itr, (double)rand()/RAND_MAX};
        //should continue evaluating the function without exiting
        pause(0.001); //To allow some interval for 'makearray' to store it
    }
}

template<size_t nn>
std::array<double, nn> makearray(long int cntr, double value, long int len)
{
    std::array<double, nn> outarr; // should be able to pass the value of 'len' to 'nn'
    long int itr=0;
    begin:
    while(cntr <= prevcntr)goto begin; // should wait until the next update
    outarr[itr] = value;
    prevcntr = cntr;
    while(itr<len)
    {
        itr++;
        goto begin; // control goes back to the beginning until all the elements of the array are filled with value
    }
    //should return the array after it is fully filled
    return outarr;
}

int main()
{
    double *p=new double[];
    long int len = 100000;
    *p = makearray(feedgenerator(len), len)

    // I should be able to call these as nested functions as above

    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    cout<<*p[i]<<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Question is how do I return a value without exiting the `feedgenerator` function. If I try to get all the values at once then it wouldn't mimic the data feed. Data feed is essentially, the same value being updated, sequentially.

To store the data, `makearray` is being used (*vector* shouldn't be used as it is extremely slow).

Overall the idea is, `feedgenerator` should update the same value with an increasing **counter** (in the real scenario **counter** will be the **time** and **value** will be **price** etc.) and `makearray` should store the data (Unless I store the data, the data would be lost, as in the case of data feed from stock exchange) for subsequent analysis.

In `makearray`, I want to pass the **length of the array** as an argument of the function, so that it can be controlled by another program. How can it be done is not clear to me.

The code in it's present form, doesn't compile.

Comment: You're likely searching for coroutines.

Comment: *vector shouldn't be used as it is extremely slow* - a very bold claim. An `std::vector` after `reserve()` call to prevent reallocations should be exactly as fast as C-style array.

Comment: "vector shouldn't be used as it is extremely slow" ... well, you are attempting to copy a rather big array. That is rather inefficient compared to moving a `std::vector`.

Comment: full computation (it's very lengthy code) should remain under ```10``` 'microseconds'. I used ```vector``` with ```push_back``` to put the values. It's going far beyond ```10``` 'microseconds'. Since it's high frequency trading, I cannot allow such high computation time.

Comment: `begin: while(cntr <= prevcntr)goto begin;` ... what will make it exit that loop if the condition is true when you get here?

Comment: using vector with pushback to add the values is wrong when you want it to be fast. You used `std::vector` wrong and then blamed the vector for being slow. Using `push_back` to add `100000` elements one by one being slow should not be a surprise. Instead you should resize the vector once and then access existing elements.

Comment: Why the usage of `goto`?

Comment: I used ```goto``` so that the code can check if and when the value gets updated.

Comment: *vector shouldn't be used as it is extremely slow* -- Any mention of the slowness of anything in C++ should be accompanied by the compiler, compiler version, and optimization switches used to build the program.  If you are running an unoptimized, "debug" build, then the timings you are observing are meaningless.

Comment: @csk7 -- *I used goto so that the code can check if and when the value gets updated.* -- All it did was obfuscate the code, and probably got a chunk of people to skip your question because they don't want to waste their time untangling spaghetti code.  How would you have written this if `goto` didn't exist (like it does in many other high-level languages)?

Comment: Re: _"I used goto so that the code can check..."_ - How is that helping here: `begin: while(cntr <= prevcntr)goto begin;`? If the condition is `true` you have an infinite loop (with undefined behavior as a result).

Comment: "how to return a value without exiting a function" - `return` exits (returns from) a function. There's no way to `return` a value without that `return` also causing function exit.

Answer (score 0):

> Question is how do I return a value without exiting the feedgenerator function

Because you are trying to mimic the data feed stream from stock exchange, so, I think you should consider to use thread. Example:

```cpp
#include <unistd.h>

#include <deque>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

#include <iostream>

class FeedGenerator {
  long int max_length;
  std::deque<double> queue;
  std::mutex mutex;
  std::thread thread;
  bool stop;
public:
  FeedGenerator(long int len) : 
      max_length(len), stop(false),
      thread(&FeedGenerator::run, this) {
  }

  virtual ~FeedGenerator() {
    stop = true;
    thread.join();
  }

  // Get the latest `len` values
  int getData(std::vector<double>& vec, int len) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    if (queue.empty()) return 0;
    int nlen = std::min((size_t)len, queue.size());
    vec.resize(nlen);
    std::copy(queue.end() - nlen, queue.end(), vec.begin());
    return nlen;
  }

private:
  void run() {
    srand(time(0));
    while (!stop)
    {
      {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
        queue.push_back((double)rand()/RAND_MAX);
        if (queue.size() >= max_length) {
          queue.pop_front();
        }
      }
      usleep(1000);
    }
  }
};

int main()
{
  long int len = 100000;
  FeedGenerator feedgenerator(len);

  sleep(1);

  std::vector<double> p;
  feedgenerator.getData(p, 10); // get the latest 10 values

  for(int i=0;i<p.size();i++)
  std::cout << p[i] << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```